# Calculate probability of getting half as many heads as coin tosses.

Tags: code-golf, math, probability-theory

Write a program that, given a small positive even integer from standard input, calculates the probability that flipping that many coins will result in half as many heads.

For example, given 2 coins the possible outcomes are:

```
HH HT TH TT
```

where H and T are heads and tails. There are 2 outcomes (`HT` and `TH`) that are half as many heads as the number of coins. There are a total of 4 outcomes, so the probability is 2/4 = 0.5.

This is simpler than it looks.

Test cases:

```
2 -> 0.5
4 -> 0.375
6 -> 0.3125
8 -> 0.2734375
```

Comment: We can assume the coins are perfect and there's an even chance of getting heads or tails?

Comment: Do we need to print the output to stdout?

Comment: @Juan yes. @Dogbert yes.

Comment: Could we get some more test cases to verify our solutions?

Comment: @Dogbert  - done

Comment: Does the output have to be actually printed out or is computing enough?  I've got a couple of answers I could shave characters from if I migrated from complete program to interactive session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### J, 22 <s>19</s> (killer approach)

I got down to this while golfing my Haskell answer.

```
%/@:>:@i.&.(".@stdin)_
```

(same I/O as [my other J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/calculate-probability-of-getting-half-as-many-heads-as-coin-tosses/1221#1221))

Comment: This gives an error for me: `0 1|domain error: script
|   %/    >:i.&.(".@stdin)_
`

Comment: @david4dev Ouch.  My leftover script file didn't work either.  I don't remember where I messed up, but the version you tested is faulty indeed.  It's now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## Pari/GP - <strike>32</strike> <strike>30</strike> 34 chars

```
print(binomial(n=input(),n\2)/2^n)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't consider a programming language having a built in binomial function.

Comment: 32 characters: `print(binomial(n=input,n\2)/2^n)`.

Answer (score 3):

**Python 53 Characters**

```
i=r=1.;exec"r*=(2*i-1)/i/2;i+=1;"*(input()/2);print r
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 39 <s>43</s> <s>46</s>

```
main=do x<-readLn;print$foldr1(/)[1..x]
```

Demonstration:

```
$ runhaskell coins.hs <<<2
0.5
$ runhaskell coins.hs <<<4
0.375
$ runhaskell coins.hs <<<6
0.3125
$ runhaskell coins.hs <<<8
0.2734375
```

Comment: I get an error: `Undefined variable "readln"`

Comment: @david4dev the 'L' in `readLn` is a capital one.

Comment: I think `main=do x<-readLn;print$foldr1(/)[1..x]` does the same thing and saves 3 bytes?

Comment: Indeed. Merging, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Excel, 25

Not quite according to spec, though :)

Name a cell `n` and then type the following into another cell:

```
=COMBIN(n,n/2)/POWER(2,n)
```

Comment: Excel actually implements the ^ properly, so you can cut out a few characters that way.

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript - 30 chars

Limitation - only works for inputs less than 63

```
'0.'\~..),1>\2//{{*}*}%~\/5@?*
```

test cases

```
$ echo 2 | ruby golfscript.rb binom.gs 
0.50
$ echo 4 | ruby golfscript.rb binom.gs 
0.3750
$ echo 6 | ruby golfscript.rb binom.gs 
0.312500
$ echo 8 | ruby golfscript.rb binom.gs 
0.27343750
```

Analysis

`'0.'` GS doesn't do floating point, so we'll fake it by writing an integer after this
`\~` Pull the input to the top of the stack and convert to an integer
`..` Make 2 copies of the input
`),1>`Create a list from 1..n
`\2//`Split the list into 1..n/2 and n/2+1..n
`{{*}*}%`Multiply the elements of the two sublists giving (n/2)! and n!/(n/2)!
`~`Extract those two numbers onto the stack
`\`Swap the two numbers around
`/`Divide
`5@?*`Multiply by 5**n. This is the cause of the limitation given above

Comment: I'm curious as to why the limitation. Are you using Gosper's hack to generate all the combinations? The idea occurred to me (and the spec doesn't say anything about execution time).

Comment: Golfscript doesn't have a float point variable class, so what he does is calculate an integer that written after the string `0.` is the decimal part of the answer, but that method leaves out the required 0 when the chance grows less than 10%.

Comment: @Peter, what eBusiness said :)

Answer (score 2):

### J, 25 (natural approach)

```
((!~-:)%2&^)&.(".@stdin)_
```

Sample use:

```
$ echo -n 2 | jconsole coins.ijs 
0.5
$ echo -n 4 | jconsole coins.ijs
0.375
$ echo -n 6 | jconsole coins.ijs
0.3125
$ echo -n 8 | jconsole coins.ijs 
0.273438
```

It's all self-explanatory, but for a rough split of responsibilities:

- `!~ -:` could be thought of as *binomial(x,x/2)*
- `% 2&^` is "divided by *2^x*"
- `&. (". @ stdin) _` for I/O

Answer (score 2):

### GNU Octave - 36 Characters

```
disp(binopdf((n=input(""))/2,n,.5));
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 39 characters

```
p 1/(1..gets.to_i).inject{|a,b|1.0*b/a}
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 10

This will take more than ten bytes of calculator memory because there is a program header, but there are only ten bytes of code.

```
binompdf(Ans,.5,.5Ans

//Equivalently:

2^~AnsAns nCr (.5Ans
```

This takes input in the form `[number]:[program name]`; adding an Input command uses three more bytes. `~` is the unary minus token.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - <strike>50</strike> <strike>57</strike> 54 chars

```
p (1..(n=gets.to_i)/2).reduce(1.0){|r,i|r*(n+1-i)/i/4}
```

Comment: This calculates nCr not the probability.

Comment: @david4dev, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 20

```
f=:(]!~[:<.2%~])%2^]
```

examples:

```
f 2
0.5
f 4
0.375
f 6
0.3125
f 8
0.273438
```

Comment: The question asks for input from STDIN, not a function.

Comment: @Dogbert: I know; I forgot to mention this. I intended to update it...

Answer (score 1):

**APL <strike>21</strike> 15 chars**

```
((N÷2)!N)÷2*N←⎕
```

For where it doesn't render right

```
((N{ColonBar}2)!N){ColonBar}2*N{LeftArrow}{Quad}
```

Where everything in {} are APL specific symbols like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28codepage%29).

Comment: Is the last character supposed to be a square?

Comment: Yes it should be the quad symbol.

Comment: I get `�[token]: � undefined`

Comment: I guess this is a coding issue. In [NARS2000](http://www.nars2000.org/) you can copy paste it as is.

Answer (score 1):

## Windows PowerShell, 45

```
($p=1)..($n="$input"/2)|%{$p*=(1+$n/$_)/4}
$p
```

Meh.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 29

```
n=input('');binopdf(n/2,n,.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

### PostScript, 77

```
([)(%stdin)(r)file token{2 idiv}if def
1
1 1[{[exch div 1 add 4 div mul}for
=
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 19

```
f=2^-# #!/(#/2)!^2&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 86 bytes

```
a=prompt(f=function(n){return n?n*f(n-1):1});alert(f(a)/(f(a/2)*f(a/2)*Math.pow(2,a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 99

This is a naive approach, I suppose, and fR0DDY's solution is much cooler, but at least I am able to solve it.

[**Try it here**](https://ideone.com/lboisi)

```python
from itertools import*
n=int(input())
print(sum(n/2==i.count("H")for i in product(*["HT"]*n))/2**n)
```

## Python 2, 103

```python
from itertools import*
n=int(raw_input())
print sum(n/2==i.count("H")for i in product(*["HT"]*n))/2.**n
```

Answer (score 0):

## Objective-C:

### <strike>152</strike> 148 bytes for just the function.

Class methods, headers, and UI are not included within the code.

Input: an `int` value determinining the number of coins.

Output: a `float` value determining the probability.

```
-(float)calcPWithCoins:(int)x {int i=0;int j=0;for (int c=x;c<1;c+-){i=i*c;} for(int d=x/2;d<1;d+-){j=j*d;} return (((float)i/(float)j)/powf(2,x));}
```

### Ungolfed:

```
-(float)calcPWithCoints:(int)x
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int c = x; c < 1; c+-) {
         i = i * c;
    }
    // Calculate the value of x! (Factorial of x)

    for (int d = x / 2; d < 1; d+-)
         j = j * d;
    }
    // Calculate (x/2)! (Factorial of x divided by 2)

    return (((float)i / (float)j) / powf(2, x));
    /* Divides i! by (i/2)!, then divides that result (known as the nCr) by 2^x.
    This is all floating-point and precise. If I didn't have casts in there,
    It would be Integer division and, therefore, wouldn't have any decimal
    precision. */
}
```

This is based off of the [Microsoft Excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1232/42145). In C and Objective-C, the challenge is in hard-coding the algorithms.