# Count, Replace, Add Up!

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, arithmetic, array

#### Definition

Define the **n**<sup>th</sup> term of the CRAU sequence as follows.

1. Begin with the singleton array **A = [n]**.
2. Do the following **n** times:

   For each integer **k** in **A**, replace the entry **k** with **k** natural numbers, counting from **1** to **k**.
3. Compute the sum of all integers in **A**.

For example, if **n = 3**, we start with the list **[3]**.

We replace **3** with **1, 2, 3**, yielding **[1, 2, 3]**.

We now replace **1**, **2**, and **3** with **1**, **1, 2** and **1, 2, 3** (resp.), yielding **[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]**.

Finally, we perform the same replacements as in the previous step for all six integers in the array, yielding **[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]**.

The sum of the resulting integers is **15**, so this is the third CRAU number.

#### Task

Write a program of a function that, given a strictly positive integer **n** as input, computes the **n**<sup>th</sup> term of the CRAU sequence.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). May the shortest code in bytes win!

#### Test cases

```
 1 ->       1
 2 ->       4
 3 ->      15
 4 ->      56
 5 ->     210
 6 ->     792
 7 ->    3003
 8 ->   11440
 9 ->   43758
10 ->  167960
11 ->  646646
12 -> 2496144
13 -> 9657700
```

#### Related

- [Simplicial polytopic numbers](http://oeis.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytopic_numbers)
- [OEIS A001791: Binomial coefficients C(2n,n-1)](https://oeis.org/A001791)

Comment: Is there a limit on the maximum number the program can handle? i.e. is it acceptable if my program returns a stack overflow for 13?

Comment: As long as your *algorithm* works for arbitrarily large numbers, your implementation may error if the input is too big.

Comment: This seems a rather roundabout way to present a challenge to compute `choose(2*n,n-1)`.

Comment: @xnor http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30500547#30500547

Comment: I'm calling it a dupe of a previous (disguised) binomial challenge. Maybe you can instead have the output be the full list without summing?

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Unfortunately this challenge is too similar to [Code Golf: Number of paths!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/code-golf-number-of-paths) to warrant a separate post. I recommend posting future challenges to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where they can get meaningful feedback before being posted to the main site. ;-P

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thank you. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
EGqXn
```

[Try it online,](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RUdxWG4&input=NQ) or [verify all test cases!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RUdxWG4&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5IDEwIDExIDEyIDEzXQ)

Explanation:

```
E       #Double the input
 Gq     #Push "input - 1"
   Xn   #Calculate "nchoosek" on the two numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 65 bytes

```python
def f(k):
 n,p=2*k,1
 for i in range(1,k):p=p*n//i;n-=1
 return p
```

Explanation: It's a simplified version of n choose k. See [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A001791).

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 27 bytes

```
$
$.`$*
M!&+%`.+(?=1)|^.+
0
```

Input in unary, using `0` as the unary digit.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JAokLmAkKgpNISYrJWAuKyg_PTEpfF4uKwow&input=MDAwMA&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 5 bytes

```
<:!+:
```

Uses the binomial coefficient of (2*n*, *n*-1).

For **22 bytes**, this is a possible solution based on using the process described in the challenge.

```
[:+/([:;<@(1+i.)"0)^:]
```

### Usage

Note: Extra commands used to format output for multiple input.

```
   f =: <:!+:
   (,.f"0) >: i. 13
 1       1
 2       4
 3      15
 4      56
 5     210
 6     792
 7    3003
 8   11440
 9   43758
10  167960
11  646646
12 2496144
13 9657700
```

### Explanation

```
<:!+:  Input: n
   +:  Double the value of n to get 2*n
<:     Decrement n to get n-1
  !    Calculate the binomial coefficient of (2*n, n-1) and return

[:+/([:;<@(1+i.)"0)^:]  Input: n
                     ]  Identify function, gets the value n
    (     ...     )^:   Repeat the following n times with an initial value [n]
          (    )"0        Means rank 0, or to operate on each atom in the list
             i.           Create a range from 0 to that value, exclusive
           1+             Add 1 to each to make the range from 1 to that value
        <@                Box the value
     [:;                  Combine the boxes and unbox them to make a list and return
[:+/                    Sum the values in the list after n iterations and return
```