# Count Up, Replace, Repeat!

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, arithmetic, array

#### Definition

Define the **n**<sup>th</sup> array of the CURR sequence as follows.

1. Begin with the singleton array **A = [n]**.
2. For each integer **k** in **A**, replace the entry **k** with **k** natural numbers, counting up from **1** to **k**.
3. Repeat the previous step **n - 1** more times.

For example, if **n = 3**, we start with the array **[3]**.

We replace **3** with **1, 2, 3**, yielding **[1, 2, 3]**.

We now replace **1**, **2**, and **3** with **1**; **1, 2** and **1, 2, 3** (resp.), yielding **[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]**.

Finally, we perform the same replacements as in the previous step for all six integers in the array, yielding **[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]**. This is the third CURR array.

#### Task

Write a program of a function that, given a strictly positive integer **n** as input, computes the **n**<sup>th</sup> CURR array.

The output has to be a *flat* list of some kind (and array returned from a function, a string representation of your language's array syntax, whitespace-separated, etc.).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). May the shortest code in bytes win!

#### Test cases

```
 1 -> [1]
 2 -> [1, 1, 2]
 3 -> [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
 4 -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 5 -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 6 -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Related: [Count, Replace, Add Up!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83432/count-replace-add-up) ._.

Comment: Can we take the input as a singleton array (like `[2]`) rather than an integer?

Comment: @Mego Let's keep it at integers.

Comment: I feel like there should be an OEIS sequence for this.

Comment: @DanTheMan It's not really an *integer* sequence in its current form, but I guess it could be turned into one by concatenating the results for all positive integers.

Comment: @Dennis There are a lot of sequences that are made by reading the rows of a table, and I think this would count as a table.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Jelly, 3 bytes

```
R¡F
```

[Try it online](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsKhRg&input=&args=Mw)

### Explanation

```
R¡F    Argument n

R      Yield range [1..n]
 ¡     Repeat n times
  F    Flatten the result
```

Comment: That is... simply brilliant... compared to my Jelly answer.

Comment: Great first post!

Answer (score 17):

### Python, 50 bytes

```python
lambda i:eval("[i "+"for i in range(1,i+1)"*i+"]")
```

Scope abuse! For example, for `i=3`, the string to be evaluated expands to.

```python
[i for i in range(1,i+1)for i in range(1,i+1)for i in range(1,i+1)]
```

Somehow, despite using the function input variable `i` for everything, Python distinguishes each iteration index as belonging to a separate scope as if the expression were

```python
[l for j in range(1,i+1)for k in range(1,j+1)for l in range(1,k+1)]
```

with `i` the input to the function.

Comment: This trick works in Firefox 30+ too and saved me 3 bytes, thanks!

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Both python and JavaScript have `eval`, obviously the code itself needs to be ported but I thought you could assume that anyway.

Comment: @Neil Oh, I see - I completely misunderstood :)

Answer (score 12):

### 05AB1E, <s>6</s> 3 bytes

```
DFL
```

**Explained**

```
D     # duplicate input
 F    # input times do
  L   # range(1,N)
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=REZM&input=Mw)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Adnan

Comment: `DFL` is 3 bytes shorter :)

Comment: @Adnan: Didn't know L worked like that on lists. A bit surprising that it flattens automatically.

Comment: It's actually a bug which I've never fixed :p.

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 33 bytes

```
$
$.`$*0
+%(M!&`1.*(?=0)|^.+
O`.+
```

Input and output in unary.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JAokLmAkKjAKKyUoTSEmYDEuKig_PTApfF4uKwpPYC4r&input=MTEx)

Even though I didn't use the closed form for the related challenge, adapting this answer was surprisingly tricky.

Comment: `+%(M!&` is the longest tag that I would ever see.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 82 bytes

```python
lambda n:[1+bin(i)[::-1].find('1')for i in range(1<<2*n-1)if bin(i).count('1')==n]
```

This isn't the shortest solution, but it illustrates an interesting method:

- Write down the first `2^(2*n-1)` numbers in binary
- Keep those with exactly `n` ones
- For each number, count the number of trailing zeroes, and add 1.

Answer (score 4):

### Actually, 9 bytes

```
;#@`♂RΣ`n
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OyNAYOKZglLOo2Bu&input=Mw)

Explanation:

```
;#@`♂RΣ`n
;#@        dupe n, make a singleton list, swap with n
   `♂RΣ`n  call the following function n times:
    ♂R       range(1, k+1) for k in list
      Σ      concatenate the ranges
```

Thanks to Leaky Nun for a byte, and inspiration for another 2 bytes.

Comment: `;#@"♂R♂i"*ƒ` saves a byte

Comment: @LeakyNun Good catch - `;#@\`♂R♂i\`n` saves another one!

Comment: I was about to try summation, lol.

Comment: I think 9 is going to be the optimal solution here

Comment: Your link is still outdated.

Answer (score 4):

### C#, 128 Bytes

```
List<int>j(int n){var l=new List<int>(){n};for(;n>0;n--)l=l.Select(p=>Enumerable.Range(1,p)).SelectMany(m=>m).ToList();return l;
```

Comment: With `using static System.Linq.Enumerable`, you can do this: `int[]J(int n){var l=new[]{n};while (n-- > 0){l = l.Select(p => Range(1, p)).SelectMany(m => m).ToArray();}return l;}`

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 11 bytes

```
{∊⍳¨∘∊⍣⍵+⍵}
```

Test:

```
      {∊⍳¨∘∊⍣⍵+⍵} 3
1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3
```

Explanation:

- `+⍵`: starting with `⍵`,
- `⍣⍵`: do the following `⍵` times:

  - `⍳¨∘∊`: flatten the input, and then generate a list [1..N] for each N in the input
- `∊`: flatten the result of that

Comment: Simpler: `{(∊⍳¨)⍣⍵⊢⍵}`

Comment: @Adám: Ah, yes, trains work differently from J. I'd started out with `{(∊∘(⍳¨))⍣⍵+⍵}` and then thought, *how can I get rid of those braces?*

Answer (score 2):

## J, 18 bytes

```
([:;<@(1+i.)"0)^:]
```

Straight-forward approach based on the process described in the challenge.

### Usage

```
   f =: ([:;<@(1+i.)"0)^:]
   f 1
1
   f 2
1 1 2
   f 3
1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3
   f 4
1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
```

### Explanation

```
([:;<@(1+i.)"0)^:]  Input: n
                 ]  Identity function, gets the value n
(     ...     )^:   Repeat the following n times with an initial value [n]
      (    )"0        Means rank 0, or to operate on each atom in the list
         i.           Create a range from 0 to that value, exclusive
       1+             Add 1 to each to make the range from 1 to that value
    <@                Box the value
 [:;                  Combine the boxes and unbox them to make a list and return
                    Return the final result after n iterations
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 14 bytes

```
{_a\{:,:~:)}*}
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=3%0A%0A%7B_a%5C%7B%3A%2C%3A~%3A)%7D*%7D%0A%0A~p&input=3)

#### Explanation

```
_a   e# Duplicate N and wrap it in an array.
\    e# Swap with other copy of N.
{    e# Do this N times...
  :, e#   Turn each x into [0 1 ... x-1].
  :~ e#   Unwrap each of those arrays.
  :) e#   Increment each element.
}*
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 33 bytes

```haskell
f n=iterate(>>= \a->[1..a])[n]!!n
```

Thanks to nimi for saving a byte.

A pointfree version is longer (35 bytes):

```haskell
(!!)=<<iterate(>>= \a->[1..a]).pure
```

Comment: `iterate(>>= \a->[1..a])` for one byte less.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

*1 byte saved with some inspiration from Essari's answer.*

```
Flatten@Nest[Range,{#},#]&
```

Fairly straightforward: for input `x` we start with `{x}` and then apply the `Range` to it `x` times (`Range` is `Listable` which means that it automatically applies to the integers inside arbitrarily nested lists). At the end `Flatten` the result.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```python
def f(k):N=[k];exec('A=N;N=[]\nfor i in A:N+=range(1,i+1)\n'*k+'print(N)')
```

This is just a straightforward translation of the problem description to code.

Edit: Saved one byte thanks to @Dennis.

Comment: Your `print` can go outside the `exec`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had at first, but it simply prints `[k]` for some reason. I gave up trying to figure out if it was a scope issue or something else.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a [scope issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15086040). It works fine in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```
f=n=>eval(`[${`for(n of Array(n+1).keys())`.repeat(n--)}n+1]`)
```

Port of @xnor's Python answer.

Comment: I tried this with Firefox 42 (`SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression` ) and Babel (`Unexpected token (1:21)`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, but I have no idea; I do in fact have Firefox 42 on one of my machines for some reason and I double-checked and it ran fine there. (I also checked Firefox 37 and 47 just to be sure.)

Comment: Huh, the page didn't refresh and I tested your old version. The new one works just fine.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, it looks like a stray `)` crept into that version somehow.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <s>60</s> 49 bytes

Pretty straightforward use of `unlist` and `sapply`.

```
y=x=scan();for(i in 1:x)y=unlist(sapply(y,seq));y
```

Thanks to @MickyT for saving 11 bytes

Comment: @MickyT thx for the tip, I can use `seq` to lower the byte count

Comment: Sorry I misread the question

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 59 bytes

```
(fn[n](nth(iterate #(mapcat(fn[x](range 1(inc x)))%)[n])n))
```

Explanation:

Really straight forward way to solve the problem. Working from the inside out:

```
(1) (fn[x](range 1(inc x))) ;; return a list from 1 to x
(2) #(mapcat (1) %)         ;; map (1) over each item in list and flatten result
(3) (iterate (2) [n])       ;; call (2) repeatedly e.g. (f (f (f [n])))
(4) (nth (3) n))            ;; return the nth value of the iteration
```

Answer (score 2):

### php 121

Not really very much in the way of tricks behind this one.
Flattening an array in php isn't short so it's necessary to build it flat in the first place

```
<?php for($a=[$b=$argv[1]];$b--;)$a=array_reduce($a,function($r,$v){return array_merge($r,range(1,$v));},[]);print_r($a);
```

Comment: Keeping it flat is a good idea. But callback functions aren´t short either. Beat You by 15 bytes. You can save 4 bytes with the short tag `<?` or 6 bytes with `-r` and no tag.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
usSMGQ]Q
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=usSMGQ%5DQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3&debug=0)

```
usSMGQ]Q   input as Q

u    Q     repeat for Q times,
      ]Q   starting as [Q]:

  SMG          convert each number in the array to its range
 s             flatten

           then implicitly prints the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 7 bytes

Quick, before Dennis answers (jk)

```
WR€F$³¡
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=V1LigqxGJMKzwqE&input=Mw&args=Mw)

```
WR€F$³¡  Main monadic chain. Argument: z

W        Yield [z].
     ³¡  Repeat the following z times:
 R€          Convert each number in the array to the corresponding range.
   F         Flatten the array.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```
def f(n):a=[n];exec'a=sum([range(1,i+1)for i in a],[]);'*n;print a
```

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @xnor. Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Dennis♦.

Comment: You can remove the parens around `exec`. In Python 2, it's a keyword, not a function. I count 68 bytes btw.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, that means I miscounted and it was originally 69 bytes...

Answer (score 1):

### F# , 63 bytes

```
fun n->Seq.fold(fun A _->List.collect(fun k->[1..k])A)[n]{1..n}
```

Returns an anonymous function taking n as input.

Replaces every entry k in A with [1..k], repeats the process n times, starting with A = [n].

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, 58 Bytes

Meant to run directly in the a playground, with n set to the input:

```
var x=[n];for i in 0..<n{x=x.reduce([]){$0+[Int](1...$1)}}
```

Ungolfed, with most short hand notation reverted:

```
let n = 3 //input

var x: Array<Int> = [n]
for i in 0..<n {
    x = x.reduce(Array<Int>[], combine: { accumulator, element in
        accumulator + Array<Int>(1...element)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 159 Bytes

**Procedure**

```
int[] q(int y){int z[]=new int[]{y};for(int i=0;i<y;i++){int d=0,a=0;for(int c:z)d+=c;int[]r=new int[d];for(int c:z)for(int j=0;j<c;)r[a++]=++j;z=r;}return z;}
```

**Usage**

```
public static void main(String[] args){String out = "["; int [] b = q(6);for(int c:b)out+=c+", ";System.out.println(out+"]");}

public static int[] q(int y){int z[]=new int[]{y};for(int i=0;i<y;i++){int d=0,a=0;for(int c:z)d+=c;int[]r=new int[d];for(int c:z)for(int j=0;j<c;)r[a++]=++j;z=r;}return z;}
```

*Sample output:*

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 49

- 1 byte saved thanks to @Dennis.

Piped recursive functions FTW!

```bash
f()((($1))&&xargs -l seq|f $[$1-1]||dd)
f $1<<<$1
```

`n` is passed on the command-line.  Output is newline-separated.

The use of `dd` causes statistics to be sent to STDERR.  I think this is OK, but if not, `dd` can be replaced with `cat` at a cost of 1 extra byte.

Comment: Extraneous output to STDERR is allowed by default. You can replace `{...;}` with `(...)` to save a byte.

Comment: @Dennis yes, of course!  Apparently you got [this tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41201/11259) from me :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

A simple recursive approach.

```ruby
->n,a=[n]{n>0?F[n-1,a.flat_map{[*1.._1]}]:a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3dXTt8nQSbaPzYqvz7Azs3aLzdA11EvXSchJL4nMTC6qjtQz19OINY2tjrRJrIXqWFSi4RRvHQjgLFkBoAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 53 bytes

A subroutine:

```
{($i)=@_;for(1..$i){my@c;push@c,1..$_ for@_;@_=@c}@_}
```

See it in action as

```
perl -e'print "$_ " for sub{($i)=@_;for(1..$i){my@c;push@c,1..$_ for@_;@_=@c}@_}->(3)'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 61 bytes

```
def f(n);a=[n];n.times{a=a.map{|i|(1..i).to_a}.flatten};a;end
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to PPCG. A short explanation would be nice!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unless the challenge overrules this [all submissions need to be full programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422), not just snippets. (And in this case, the challenge actually confirms this requirement.)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>100</s> 98 bytes

Run with `php -r '<code>' <n>`.

```
for($a=[$n=$argv[1]];$n--;$a=$b)for($b=[],$k=0;$c=$a[$k++];)for($i=0;$i++<$c;)$b[]=$i;print_r($a);
```

In each iteration create a temporary copy looping from 1..(first value removed) until `$a` is empty.

---

These two are still and will probably remain at 100 bytes:

```
for($a=[$n=$argv[1]];$n--;)for($i=count($a);$i--;)array_splice($a,$i,1,range(1,$a[$i]));print_r($a);
```

In each iteration loop backwards through array replacing each number with a range.

```
for($a=[$n=$argv[1]];$n--;)for($i=$c=0;$c=$a[$i+=$c];)array_splice($a,$i,1,range(1,$c));print_r($a);
```

In each iteration loop through array increasing index by previous number and replacing each indexed element with a range

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mh`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
N=cõ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1o&code=Tj1j9Q&input=Mw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 28 bytes

```perl
eval's/\d+/@{[1..$&]}/g;'x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZXZhbCdzL1xcZCsvQHtbMS4uJCZdfS9nOyd4JF8iLCJhcmdzIjoiLXAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjYifQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 9 bytes

```
Đ`⇹řƑ⇹⁻ł+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISER@07j848NhFIPWrcfbRJ@/9/YwA)

```
Đ            implicit input; Đuplicate
 `     ł     do... while top of stack is truthy
  ⇹          swap top two items on stack
   ř         řangify (element-wise)
    Ƒ        Ƒlatten array
     ⇹       swap top two items on stack
      ⁻      decrement
       +     add (to get rid of pesky 0); implicit print
```